# Need help in fetching information from HyperV Nodes using Powershell

Tags: powershell, shell-script, hyper-v

Below is my Script to fetch the information. I am getting OSStatus and uptime as blank in output. Can some one Please help me to get the output using "Get-VM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters" and point out what mistake I am making here.

```
$clus = Read-Host 'Enter the Cluster Name'
$Nodes = Get-clusternode -Cluster $clus
foreach($Node in $Nodes)
          {
$VMs = Get-VM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters | Select VMName, IPAddresses, State
    foreach($VM in $VMs)
    {
       $results = [ordered]@{

            'NodeName' = $Node;    
            'VMName' = $VM.VMName; 
            'IPaddress' = $VM.IPAddresses[0];
            'Status' = $VM.State;
            'AdapterStatus' = $VM.Status[0];
            'OSStatus' = $VM.OSStatus;
            'Uptime' = $VM.Uptime
            }
    $Output = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $results
    Write-Output $Output
        } 
    }
```

I would also like to know if we can have output from separate foreach loops and put it in one array and format it for output at the end of output.

Below is Output I am getting. Blank for OSStatus and Uptime.

```
NodeName      : ABC
VMName        : System1
IPaddress     : 192.168.1.6
Status        : Running
AdapterStatus : Degraded
OSStatus      : 
Uptime        : 

NodeName      : ABC
VMName        : System2
IPaddress     : 192.168.1.7
Status        : Running
AdapterStatus : Degraded
OSStatus      : 
Uptime        : 

NodeName      : ABC
VMName        : System3
IPaddress     : 192.168.1.8
Status        : Running
AdapterStatus : Degraded
OSStatus      : 
Uptime        :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like some information that you need is in the output of `Get-VM` and gets lost when you only select the NetworkAdapters Property. That's why I changed it below. it loops over the VM's now and selects the NetworkAdapters Property during the loop.

I also:

- Put everything in a `PSCustomObject` directly, so no need for `New-Object` or `[ordered]`
- Put the `$results` Variable before the `foreach` loop
- Added `| ft -Autosize` to your `Write-Output` so it formats it the way you want to (if you want to use the output of the script further in your script, remove `| ft -autosize` again, it's only good for cosmetic reasons)
- Specified the `ClusterObject` in your `Get-VM` - I'm not so sure about that since I don't work with clusters, but I think you need to specify this information, otherwise it would only read local VM's, never from a remote cluster.
- There was no Property for `OSStatus`. I think you meant `OperationalStatus`. I changed it to that.

Here's the code

```
$clus = Read-Host 'Enter the Cluster Name'
$Nodes = Get-clusternode -Cluster $clus
$results = @()
foreach($Node in $Nodes)
{
    $VMs = Get-VM -ClusterObject $Node
    foreach($VM in $VMs)
    {
        $VMtmp = $VM | select -expand NetworkAdapters
        $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
            'NodeName' = $Node;    
            'VMName' = $VM.VMName; 
            'IPaddress' = $VMtmp.IPAddresses[0];
            'Status' = $VM.State;
            'AdapterStatus' = $VMtmp.Status[0];
            'OSStatus' = $VM.OperationalStatus[0];
            'Uptime' = $VM.Uptime
        }
    } 
}
Write-Output $results | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon. It works and clears my doubt as well.